# Google Chrome seems to wrongfully flag my website as dangerous

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security

I've gone to search console (https://search.google.com/search-console/security-issues) and this is the best they've given in terms of detail.

[image: issues in trilight.cloud/alerts]

There's no specifics given about what is wrong. The html and js are too long to post here, but one can access them from https://trilight.cloud/alerts

The dangerous warning when I visit the site:

[image: warning showing danger when visiting site]

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Possibly if not probably the cloud site is on a blacklist because _other_ websites (users) of the site have created a history of user pages on the site up to no good. If you are not one of them, try switching to another site provider.

Answer (score -1):

This was due to a hidden form. I latter went on to request a review from https://search.google.com/search-console for my website. This is a rather convoluted process, which involved creating a new property for your website and requesting a review